# How to get last_access_time in Firebase Storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm developing a Flutter web application, and I use **Firebase Storage** to store some files.

I'd like to remove files if nobody accesses them for a certain time.

Is there a way to do that? if not, I need to get the `last_access_time` for each file to delete them myself.

I got`timeCteated` and `updated` from `Metadata`, but I can't find anything related to `last_access_time`.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage don't expose any property that indicates when the file was last accessed. I'm not even sure if Cloud Storage itself tracks such a value.

If you want to delete files based on their last access time, you will have to track that yourself. For example, whenever your app reads the file for a user, also have it write a value to a cloud hosted database (such as Firebase's Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore). Then you can periodically query that database, and delete the outdated files (and data).

---

A neat trick could be to use Firestore's [time-to-live](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl) (TTL) feature for this. In steps:

- For each file in storage, you have a corresponding document with: a field `deleteAt`, and also a field with the path to the file.
- Then every time a user accesses the file, you update `deleteAt` to whenever you want to delete the file.
- Write a Cloud Function that [triggers whenever a document of this type gets deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted), and then also delete the file that the document refers to.
- Now when the document reaches it's `deletedAt` date, Firestore will automatically delete the document - and your Cloud Function will delete the corresponding file.

Comment: I'm sharing my file (PDF) over social networks, such as WhatsApp, using a direct link like this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/arabeia.appspot.com/o/18a1f072099-2f.pdf?alt=media

The file is accessed outside of my app. In this scenario, how can I implement a mechanism to get triggered or notified when the PDF file is accessed through the provided link?